# How to disable intrusive template picker dialog?

Tags: user-experience, 2sxc

Is there any global option to disable the template picker dialog for 2sxc after the application is configured? Now this dialog is popping up every page load in edit mode and interferes with general website editing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is - maybe add some context or screenshot.

My guess is you added a module to the page and didn't configure it yet - so the picker automatically appears. Just pick something - or delete the module, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Oh, my bad - I've accidentally added another App module instance to the different pane... After removing it, the configured App works as expected. Thanks!